# Is it possible to link IPython widgets less naively?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'll start with a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

Say, I have two IntSlider-widgets. I would like to have one represent x and the other x^2 (unidirectional link). Maybe I would even want the first slider to display sqrt(x^2), if I were to play with the second slider (bidirectional link).

This would,very naively, translate in something like this:

```
l1 = traitlets.link((widg1, 'value'),(widg2, 5* 'value'))
```

Which of course it doesn't, because the second tuple argument is supposed to be a string, so really I am passing 'valuevaluevaluevaluevalue'.

Anyway, would this be possible and if yes, has it already been implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link` only passes on the same value. If you want to transform the value, you need a callback:

```
def widg1_changed(name, new_value):
    widg2.value = 5 * new_value

widg1.on_trait_change(widg1_changed, 'value')
```

I don't know of a good way to do this bidirectionally at present.